# Profiling core java to check method statistics and latency at every counter

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

```
//method 1 & 2 contain calls to a number of other methods
for(int i=0; i<100;i++) {
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

I'd like to profile the above java code at every counter 'i' of the loop, and get method statistics (specifically the execution latency) at each value of i.

The methods method1() and method2() contain calls to other methods, including method calls from their dependencies.

How can I profile my code at each counter? I don't think it's possible with JProfiler.

Answer (score 0):

In JProfiler this is possible with [method splitting](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.callTree.splitting). First of all, you should wrap your calls to `method1` and `method2` into another method and pass `i` as a parameter:

```
...

for(int i=0; i<100;i++) {
   measure(i);
}

...

void measure(int i) {
   method1();
   method2();
}
```

Then profile your code, go to the call tree, select the `measure` method and choose `Split Method With a Script` from the context menu. In the script dialog that is now displayed, configure `String.valueOf(i)` as the script. For the next profiling run, you will now get the slowest executions of `measure` separately in the call tree.